# DB2 Time stamp calculation

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2

I am getting sql error for below query,
is it not possible to write as below,..

```
SELECT   some columns  FROM XXXXX.XXX_XXX
WHERE LAST_UPDT_DATE<=  CURRENT TIMESTAMP     
AND LAST_UPDT_DATE>= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -     
'2001-01-21-12.00.00.000000')              
;
```

Comment: I don't get any error from your query so provide error for further help.

Comment: DSNT408I SQLCODE = -401, ERROR:  THE OPERANDS OF AN ARITHMETIC OR COMPARISON
         OPERATION ARE NOT COMPARABLE                                       
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42818 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE

Comment: Side note: [always use an exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) with positive contiguous-range types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query:

```
SELECT   some columns  FROM XXXXX.XXX_XXX
WHERE LAST_UPDT_DATE between CURRENT TIMESTAMP     
AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -
date(to_date('2001-01-21-12.00.00','YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SS'))
```

Comment: Jens .. i think your code will give curr_ts - date . I need to have  more accuaracy.. and need to subtract curr_ts - an old  timestamp ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Usually (in standard SQL), there are colons separating hour from minute and minute from second.  I seem to remember that DB2 doesn't follow the standard with a space between day and hour, but I forget which punctuator is used.  You might also prefix the string with TIMESTAMP to emphasize/coerce it to a TIMESTAMP literal.

From the [DB2 10.1 Knowledge Centre](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008474.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F2-9-2-3-0-6):

> A string representation of a timestamp can be given a different timestamp precision by explicitly casting the value to a timestamp with a specified precision. If the string is a constant, an alternative is to precede the string constant with the TIMESTAMP keyword. For example, TIMESTAMP '2007-03-28 14:50:35.123' has the TIMESTAMP(3) data type.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all.. my requirement does not require calculating (time stamp - timestamp ).
The quesry just need to be as,

```
SELECT   some columns  FROM XXXXX.XXX_XXX
WHERE LAST_UPDT_DATE<=  CURRENT TIMESTAMP     
AND LAST_UPDT_DATE>='2001-01-21-12.00.00.000000'
;
```

which works fine.